# Drop down menu for String values in Hybris Management Console

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement to display a drop down menu for a String type in Hybris Management Console, restricting the value to some specific values.
As suggested in several forums, I tried to create this entry as an enumeration type but characters like '-' are to be allowed in the enumeration values, as this column receives some specific values which comprise of '-'.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The people advising you probably didn't understand your requirements. As such, an enumeration type is clearly not appropriate in this case. Consider the alternatives. Is there a Map Type available? What other type might allow you to achieve your goal?

Comment: Is it possible to do it by only modifying the hmc.xml file and keeping the data intact,as this is a String type?

Comment: @danday74 Why do you think the hybris enum is not appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could use the hybris Enumeration. In hybris Enum Types have a code and a name. The code is the unique representation for this enum and cannot contain a "-". The name however is a localized representation of that value and can include every character your database is able to store. Have a look here:

https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8c895989866910148d6a802f06651702.html

Additionally, hybris enables you to dynamically create new enumeration values, which is kind of nice.